# SAPUI5 Bind path from combobox control to a quickview popup

Tags: javascript, json, combobox, sapui5

I have a combobox and a separate button in a XML view. The button on press event calls a QuickView control.
The problem is that I can't populate the QuickView's data from the combobox's selected binding path.

The items of the combobox are located in a json file.

```
<ComboBox id="person" showSecondaryValues="true" 
          items="{persons>/Persons}">
            <items>
                <core:Item key="{persons>ID}" text="{persons>Name}"/>
            </items>
</ComboBox>
<Button icon="sap-icon://personnel-view" press="onPersonnelView"/>
```

The json file that is declared in manifest is :

```
{    
"Persons": [
{
  "ID": "id01",
  "Name": "name",
  "Roles": "role",
  "Mobile": "555",
  "Phone": "555",
  "Email": "info@info.info",
  "Address": "address 99",
  "CompanyID": "cid01"
}]}
```

and the manifest part :

```
    "models": {
        "persons": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "uri": "TestData/persons.json"
         }
```

The Combobox works like a charm and the binding with the "persons" model seems to be fine.

My controller looks like:

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
"use strict";
return Controller.extend("my.app.controller.Form", {

 onPersonnelView: function(oEvent) {

        this._openQuickView(oEvent);
    },

    _openQuickView: function(oEvent) {

        this._createPopover();

        var oButton = oEvent.getSource();
        jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function () {
            this._oQuickView.openBy(oButton);
        });
    },

    _createPopover: function() {
        if (!this._oQuickView) {
            this._oQuickView = sap.ui.xmlfragment("my.app.view.PersonnelQuickView", this);
            this.getView().addDependent(this._oQuickView);
        }
    }
});
});
```

The quick view shows itself but it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the QuickViewPage to the specific entry in your model.

For this it is required to get the binding path of the selected ComboBox entry and to use it as binding context of the QuickViewPage.

```
onPersonnelView: function(oEvent) {
    var item = this.byId("person").getSelectedItem();
    if (!item) {
        return;
    }
    var path = item.getBindingContext("persons").getPath();
    this._createPopover("persons>" + path);

    var oButton = oEvent.getSource();
    jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function () {
        this._oQuickView.openBy(oButton);
    });
},

_createPopover: function(path) {
    if (!this._oQuickView) {
        this._oQuickView = sap.ui.xmlfragment("my.app.view.PersonnelQuickView", this);
        this.getView().addDependent(this._oQuickView);
    }
    this._oQuickView.bindElement(path);
 }
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer!!
My problem seems to be on "getBindingContext()" because I get and undefined return. I'm trying to find out what I do wrong but I still cant.

Comment: What error do you get? It is possible that no item is selected. In this case getBindingContext fails. In this case you should not open a dialog as it does not make sense. I changed the answer accordingly. If possible create an example using JS Bin.

Comment: I gave the model name and now the getBindingContext is working.
`var bindingPath = this.byId("responsible").getSelectedItem().getBindingContext("persons").getPath();`
Actually I found one of your comments to another thread, mentioning that need to access with the name of the model.

Still the QuickView miss the data. Surely my mistake now should by on QuickView's elements binding.

e.g. `<QuickViewGroupElement label="Mobile" value="{persons>Mobile}" type="mobile"/>`

Comment: Somehow I missed the model name. It has to be passed to bindElement as well. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah I figured that! Thanks for your help @matbtt.  You helped a lot to get the binding concept more clear.